How should we characterize the relationship between two matrix representations of a linear operator with respect to two different orthonormal bases?
Nielsen / Chuang remark on page 71 of "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" that, if $| v_i \rangle$ and $|w_i \rangle$ are orthonormal bases, then the operator $U$ defined by $\sum_{i=1}^n |w_i \rangle \langle v_i|$ is unitary. They then propose the following exercise:
 "Suppose $A'$ and $A''$ are matrix representations of an operator $A$ on a vector space $V$ with respect to two different orthonormal bases, $| v_i \rangle$ and $|w_i \rangle$. Then the elements of $A'$ and $A''$ are $A'_{ij} = \langle v_i |A|v_j \rangle$ and $A''_{ij} = \langle w_i |A|w_j \rangle$ . Characterize the relationship between $A'$ and $A''$." 
I came up with the following answer and wanted to see whether it seems like a good "characterization" of the relationship between $A'$ and $A''$ of the sort that Nielsen / Chuang are likely talking about.
First note that $U$ takes any member $|v_k \rangle$ of the basis $| v_i \rangle$ to the corresponding member of the basis $| w_i \rangle$:
$$U |v_k \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n | w_i \rangle \langle v_i | v_k \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_i|v_k \rangle  |w_i \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{ik} |w_i \rangle =  |w_k\rangle $$
We can therefore characterize $A_{ij}''$ as follows:
$$A_{ij}''= \langle w_i |A| w_j \rangle = \langle U | v_i \rangle |A U | v_j \rangle = \langle v_i | U^\dagger A U | v_j \rangle $$
Further, since we know $U$ to be unitary, we have that $U^\dagger U = I$. We can thus characterize $A_{ij}'$ as follows:
$$A_{ij}' = \langle v_i | A | v_j \rangle = \langle v_i | I A I | v_j \rangle = \langle v_i | U^\dagger U A U^\dagger U | v_j \rangle = \langle U |v_i \rangle | U A U^\dagger U | v_j \rangle = \langle w_i | U A U^\dagger | w_j \rangle$$
So we have characterized $A_{ij}'$ as $\langle w_i | U A U^\dagger | w_j \rangle$ and $A_{ij}''$ as $\langle v_i | U^\dagger A U | v_j \rangle$. Does this seem like an adequate answer, or do you think that Nielsen / Chuang were asking for a different kind of characterization?

This is standard linear algebra just with the bra/ket notation. In LA we write $e_i$ for the basis vectors of one basis and however you like for the other. In short: it looks OK.

I suspect this not what they are asking for. They probably want you to write an explicit equation relating the two matrices.
Since the matrices $A'$ and $A''$ represent the same operator in different bases, by standard results in linear algebra they satisfy the relation
$$ A''=PA' P^{-1} $$
for some invertible square matrix $P$ representing the change of basis (actually, since the bases are orthonormal, it turns out that $P$ is unitary). What they are asking is to find the coefficients of the matrix $P$ explicitly in terms of the two basis $v_i$ and $w_i$.
How to do that? You should go over the old knowledge of linear algebra to understand how a matrix change under a change of basis, in particular how to write the matrix $P$ in the above equation (spoiler: the $k$-th column of $P$ has to be made of the coefficients of the linear expansion of $w_k$ when written as a linear combination of the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$).
